# OK to ask if a particuar app store's vetting is sufficient for a high risk app under non-targeted conditions?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question

I want to ask whether it is safe to install an app from a high-risk provider.  Googling has shown that Apple's app store does vetting of code to prevent stealing of information from personal information management (PIM) apps that are native to the iPhone, e.g., [here](https://www.quora.com/On-an-iOS-device-can-one-app-secretly-steal-data-from-another-one-e-g-can-a-malware-app-somehow-get-what-I-type-in-pages-in-background) and [here](https://www.washingtonpost.com/technology/2021/07/15/contacts-sharing-privacy).

The question is subjective, but I make it much more specific by describing the app provider's country of origin and it's attempts to hide that fact.  I further make it more specific by stating the assumption of not being particularly targeted.

[This stack exchange's guidance](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) links to a [description of good subjectivity](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective) in questions.  I'm on the fence as to whether my question is specific enough.  Security can be very subjective by nature.

I have posted the question on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Smartphones/comments/znvv2k/builtin_security_prevents_apps_from_stealing_data), but it isn't getting any attention, as it is not a security-oriented forum.  Reddits [mobile security forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/mobilesec) doesn't seem to have seen activity in years and I do not get response to a request to participate (it is a restricted forum).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any type of question that asks "is it safe if..." is not answerable in any meaningful way on Stack Exchange, as there is no single answer that is correct. Every visitor could have a different risk appetite and we need questions and answers to be of value to future visitors.

Having looked at your question on reddit, it would not be on topic here, as there is no useful answer.

Comment: I appreciate the response!  However, I also describe how this site's guide also references inevitability of subjectivity and how to recognize good subjectivity.  I also narrow the breadth of answers by describing how I narrow my risk appetite by opening with the assumption of being not targeted (because I recognize that if someone is out to get you and has the resources, the possibilities are endless).  Can you please speak to these things in your answer?  Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to remove any reference to "is it safe" - because that is a null question.

Comment: I try to find a way to convey that I'm not looking for a black-and-white assessment.  Maybe if anyone has experiences to share that might give an idea of the prevalence of known threats that circumvent the best practices (not special tools that target individuals).

Comment: @user2153235 - there are companies that publish those sorts of things, ranging from the annual DBIR and others, to daily status feeds, but they change a lot over time